# tool for converting .bat scripts to flowchart diagrams

Tags: batch-file, utility, flowchart

I need to analyse and find logic of a very large batch file.
Is there any tool for converting Windows `.bat`  scripts to flowcharts?
I mean visualization tool for batch files for visual analysis.

Comment: I don't believe that such a tool exists, as batch shouldn't be used in any _professional_ environment. And it would be very hard to analyze a batch file, as it can be very generic (like macros).

Comment: I have constructed large batch files with dozens of options and have had to do this very same thing... it's all manual. I used visio to create my flowchart and it took me FOREVER, not to mention anything you change basically screws you.

Comment: @4r1y4n - consider marking this answered?

Comment: @Mechanic12386: unfortunately Stackoverflow doesn't inform me when new answer comes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently (after some research) there is a product that will do this... and it's worth checking out.

It's called Visustin and can be found:
http://www.aivosto.com/vbcatalog.html

Here is a screenshot of the product:
http://www.aivosto.com/visustin-shot.gif

Also, this question might be better for Superuser?

Comment: I was looking for something similar and it is a nice idea but not really usable imo...